# Prepopulated textbox value to disappears onclick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox, onclick

My textboxes on the page are pre-populated with either required text or 'Enter Text'.

If the boxes have 'Enter Text', I'd like the those texts to disappear onclick on the box. But if nothing is entered, then the textbox returns to having pre-populated 'Enter Text'.

If the boxes are populated with other texts (other than 'Enter Text', then I'd like it to stay as is.

This is what I've got so far on the code-behind:

```
 txtBox.Attributes.Add("onblur", "if(this.value='Enter Text') {this.value=''} else if(this.value.length<=0) {this.value='" + prepopulatedText.ToString() + "'} ");
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Should I be using "onClick" instead too?

Comment: Have you heard of the `placeholder` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't worried about older browser then you can use HTML5 input property ie. `placeholder`

```
 <input type="text" name="fisrtName" placeholder="Enter your name">
```

otherwise you can do it like this

```
<input name="q" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" type="text"  onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'search'" value="search">
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/ygScQ/1/)

Comment: thanks Sachin. It doesnt work for me using the 2nd approach (we will be using older browsers). Ultimately, I just want the textbox text to disappear IF the textbox contains 'Enter Text'. I used the following codes:  

txtBox.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "if(this.value == 'Enter Text') this.value=''");

but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Winforms, you can use the [Enter event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) to remove the text. You can register them directly in the editor, or via

```
txtBox.Enter += new System.EventHandler(Enter);
txtBox.Leave+= new System.EventHandler(Leave);

private void Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtBox.Text == "Enter Text")
    {
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And the [Leave event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) to put it back.

```
private void Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtBox.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        txtBox.Text = "Enter Text";
    }
}
```